# Cannot install devtools in R version 3.4.3

Tags: r

install.pacakges("devtools")

I got the following errors. Could you please help me?

```
   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
  vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'fs' 1.2.7 is being loaded, but >= 1.3.0 is required
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'usethis'
  * removing 'C:/Users/KKK/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/usethis'
   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
   namespace 'processx' 3.3.0 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
   * removing 'C:/Users/KKK/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/callr'
  ERROR: dependency 'callr' is not available for package 'rcmdcheck'
   * removing 'C:/Users/KKK/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rcmdcheck'
 ERROR: dependencies 'usethis', 'callr', 'rcmdcheck' are not available for 
 package 'devtools'
 * removing 'C:/Users/KKK/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/devtools'
```

Comment: Have you tried installed/updated the dependent packages manually? Perhaps `install.packages(c("callr", "fs", "processx"))` to name just a few.

Comment: maybe upgrade your R?

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded R version. It works.